# Why is my Sandy Bridge i915 video adapter periodically freezing under load?

Tags: i915

When I use OpenGL at anything close to full-screen resolution, rendering, audio, and processing begin to stutter -- freezing for about a second at a time. kern.log reports:

```
[drm:i915_hangcheck_ring_idle] *ERROR* Hangcheck timer elapsed... blt ring idle [waiting on 247635, at 247635], missed IRQ?
```

...once for each "stutter" event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a similar problem, [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50033/unity-gui-pauses-freezes-for-less-than-a-few-seconds/50299) worked for me.